# ProgressDialog not stopping with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am developing a simple application which sends the pseudo random string to the server database. Here I am using AsyncTask for sending string to server and ProgressDialog in foreground. The problem is the progress dialog is not stopping and I don't gt any string at server. Maybe there is some problem in the code of sending srcetring. I am new to Android and learn from sources available on the Internet. Here is the code which I use.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void getThis(View v) {
        String str = "35" +
            Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 + 
            Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 + 
            Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 + 
            Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 + 
            Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 + 
            Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 + 
            Build.USER.length()%10 ; 
        tv.setText(str);
        UploadUniqueID uni=new UploadUniqueID(this,str);
        uni.execute(str);
    }

    class UploadUniqueID extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        Context context;
        MainActivity ma;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String id;
        public UploadUniqueID(MainActivity activity,String str) {
            ma = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            id = str;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(true); 
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // perform long running operation operation
            String id=params[0];
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/UniqueIdApp/myPHP.php");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android",id));     
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);          
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
            }            

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String...strings) {
            tv.setText("Sent"); 
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are getting any error in the logcat post here

Comment: Nope.. I am not getting any error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create and initialize the dialog in your **`UploadUniqueID`** AsyncTask class by doing:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

and just dismiss it in your `onPostExecute(...)` method as you are currently doing. Also, add the `@Override` annotation to your `onPreExecute()` method.

Comment: Hey it worked.. But its taking almost a minute to complete the process. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: @aakash It is performing a network related task, so the time varies based on how much data you're trying to pull via the Web Service. However, it is normal, what you can do is try and optimize the code on the PHP side and see if that speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to initialize your `ProgressDialog dialog` object in the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, and dismiss the progress bar in `onPostExecute(String...strings)` method. May be this will help you cheers :).

**Edited**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ProgressDialog dialog;
Button btn;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getThis(View v) {
    String str = "35" +
        Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 + 
        Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 + 
        Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 + 
        Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 + 
        Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 + 
        Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 + 
        Build.USER.length()%10 ; 
    tv.setText(str);
    UploadUniqueID uni=new UploadUniqueID(this,str);
    uni.execute(str);
}

class UploadUniqueID extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    Context context;
    MainActivity ma;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String id;
    /*public UploadUniqueID(MainActivity activity,String str) {
        ma = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        id = str;
    }*/

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        dialog.setCancelable(true); 
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform long running operation operation
        String id=params[0];
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/UniqueIdApp/myPHP.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android",id));     
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
        }            

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String...strings) {
        tv.setText("Sent"); 
        try{
    if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
        dialog.setMessage("DownLoading finished");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried Powell's solution which is almost the same as you said but its taking a minute to complete the process.. I am using micromax funbook tab in debugging mode for testing.

Comment: Your code is also working fine.. But now problem is with the time it takes to send data.

Comment: There can be several reason for that. May be the data you are downloading or getting is big. So this might take some time. As you do this in `doInBackground(String... params)` you dont have to worry about it that much.

Comment: The data is just a simple string that you see in the code. Thats why I am worried.

Comment: Are you running it on the debug mode ??? Just simply run your application once and see if the problem persisted.

Comment: Yes.. I will try that.May be thats the reason.. Thanx a lot.. I will need a lot of help in future as I am just a newbie in Android..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    public void getThis(View v) {
        String str = "35" + Build.BOARD.length() % 10 + Build.BRAND.length()
            % 10 + Build.CPU_ABI.length() % 10 + Build.DEVICE.length() % 10
            + Build.DISPLAY.length() % 10 + Build.HOST.length() % 10
            + Build.ID.length() % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10
            + Build.MODEL.length() % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10
            + Build.TAGS.length() % 10 + Build.TYPE.length() % 10
            + Build.USER.length() % 10;
        tv.setText(str);
        UploadUniqueID uni = new UploadUniqueID(this, str);
        uni.execute(str);
    }

    class UploadUniqueID extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        Context context;
        MainActivity ma;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String id;

        public UploadUniqueID(MainActivity activity, String str) {
            ma = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            id = str;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // perform long running operation operation
            String id = params[0];
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://10.0.2.2/UniqueIdApp/myPHP.php");
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android", id));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) { }

        protected void onPostExecute(String p_result) {
            super.onPostExecute(p_result);          
            tv.setText("Sent");
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dear that is just annotation and this is used to tell When we want to override a method, we can use this annotation to say to the compiler we are overriding an existing method. If the compiler finds that there is no matching method found in super class then generates a warning. This is not mandatory to use @Override when we override a method.Though it is not mandatory, it is considered as a best practice.

Comment: @BBdev -Yes i know its not mandatory but if you want to dismiss the progress dialog then you have to call it. Otherwise complier won't be able to detect it and won't call the `dialog.dismiss();`. I found only this issue that its `onPostExecute` was not getting called thatz why i suggested this solution.

Comment: Is this ??? let if i remove @Override from `oncreate` method and run my app, do you think it wont start my app ??? Just give it a try. It will run your app as i know.

Comment: @BBdev -Yes offcourse i agree with you absolutely. But when i have tested the code it wasn't showing the overridden symbol in eclipse. So  after that when i have tried to use the overridden method then it started working. I just found this problem thats why i have provided this solution only.

Comment: added override annotation but its still not stopping.